# Как выбрать интерпретатор python из venv в VisualStudioCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, venv

Создал проект в pycharm с виртуальным окружением и попытался открыть его в VSC, но он не видит python из venv.Если выбираю в ручную, то ошибка. На первом скрине, это если я с нуля создал venv в VSC, то он все видит. Второй скрин это выбор интерпретатора из готового проекта.
[image: Созданный с нуля]

[image: Нету выбора из venv]

Comment: Вы прямо по этой статье всё делали? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments